# How to pattern match int strings?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to pattern match a string representation of an int in Scala. What I really want to be able to do is something like this:

```
"1234" match {
  // Some cases
  case "five" => 5
  case Int(i) => i // Fails
  case _ => throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

One approach is this, using a regular expression. A potential problem with this is that it won't detect if the integer is too large to fit in an int.

```
val ISINT = "^([+-]?\\d+)$".r

"1234" match {
  case "five" => 5
  case ISINT(t) => t.toInt
  case _ => throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

Another approach uses a `toInt` function that returns an `Option` (borrowed from [this blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-cast-string-to-int-in-scala-string-int-conversion)). This is nice because it makes the standard library figure out whether the string contains an integer. The problem is that it forces me to nest my logic where I think it should be flat.

```
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
  try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }
}

"1234" match {
  case "five" => 5
  case t => toInt(t) match {
    case Some(i) => i
    case None => throw new RuntimeException()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a more general question that you might be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607586/scala-pattern-matching-with-reusable-condition/40610249#40610249

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a custom extractor like this

```
object Int { 
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = util.Try(s.toInt).toOption 
}
```

And use it like you wanted to

```
"1234" match {
  // Some cases
  case "five" => 5
  case Int(i) => i // works :)
  case _ => throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I really like @Jasper-M's approach for its simplicity, but I do my best [to avoid generating exceptions as a means of control flow](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)--not to mention the significant performance cost. The interesting thing is that @Jasper-M's approach is so concise and elegant it hides these details.

So if you want to try a non-exception based approach for fun:

```
val matcher = "1234" match {
  case "five" => Some(BigInt(5L))
  case regex(t) => Some(BigInt(t))
  case _ => None
}
val result: Option[Int] = matcher.filter(_.isValidInt).map(_.toInt)
```

In this case, you get an `Option[Int]]`, which is a `Some` for a good `Int` parsed from the `String` and `None` otherwise.

I would go with @Jasper-M's approach first and watch performance. If you notice anything, then consider non-exception-based approaches.

Comment: This throws an exception if the integer is too large for a `Long`.

Comment: That's true. I should've mentioned that. The question is if that's a legitimate possibility in this situation. In the real world, it is important to write code against practical, likely realities rather than (potentially) obscure theoretical possibilities. Regardless, that's a small detail that distracts from the main point, which is that exception-based solutions should rarely be your first choice. But since it bothers you, I've provided a `BigInt`-based solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just another trick with regex

```
  "1234" match {
      case number if number.matches("\\d+") => println(s"yes its a numeric value  $number")
      case _                                => println("not a numeric value")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use guard in match?

```
"12312312313123" match {
   case s: String if s.isInt => "int"
   case _ => "no int"
}

implicit class IsInt(i: String){
  def isInt: Boolean = Try(i.toInt).isSuccess
}
```